# javascript: Even after returning false, click event triggers default action: takes to the top of the page

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a script which involves a click function and it always takes me to top of the page. I tried returning false as well as event.preventDefault() function but none seem to work. Here is my code: http://jsfiddle.net/79Rzh/14/

Please help.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's ok with you get the tab's ID from another property, like `data-tab` or something;

HTML:

```
<ul class="tabs top_rounded">
    <li class="active tab top_rounded"><a href="#tab1" data-tab="tab1">Overview</a></li>
    <li class="inactive tab"><a href="#tab2" data-tab="tab2">Cast &amp; Crew</a></li>
    <li class="inactive tab"><a href="#tab3" data-tab="tab3">Reviews</a></li>
    <li class="inactive tab"><a href="#tab4" data-tab="tab4">Trivia</a></li>
    <li class="inactive tab"><a href="#tab5" data-tab="tab5">News</a></li>
</ul>
```

Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".tab_content").hide();
    $("ul.tabs li:first").addClass("active").show();
    $(".tab_content:first").show();
    $("ul.tabs li a").click(function(e) {
        $("ul.tabs li").removeClass("active");
        $(".tab_content").hide();

        $(this).parent().addClass("active top_rounded");
        var activeTab = "#" + $(this).data("tab");
        $(activeTab).fadeIn();
        e.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

[Working example](http://jsfiddle.net/karalamalar/79Rzh/16/).

When you set the `href` attribute to `activeTab` variable you actually get the whole URL like `http://somedomain.com/#tab2` and when you try to use that variable to select elements you actually doing this: `$('http://somedomain.com/#tab2')` That's why it doesn't work with `href` attribute. [HTML5 data](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/Overview.html#embedding-custom-non-visible-data-with-the-data-attributes) attributes with jQuery [`.data()`](http://api.jquery.com/data/) method works well in this kind of situations.

Comment: Hi, Thats a fantastic tip. I tried it with your code but it still jumps to the top of the page. Even if you see in your example, it still jumps.. Is there a better way to do it instead of anchor tags?

Comment: It's not jumping because of anchor tags. It jumps because when you switch tabs, one of the tabs have a big content that changes document height. If you add lots of `<br />` at the bottom of the page you'll see no more jumping. [example](http://jsfiddle.net/karalamalar/79Rzh/16/)

Answer (score 0):

Your code is working. See http://jsfiddle.net/79Rzh/15/.

In my update I have removed the extra `<br>`. Now it seems fine.

The fact is, if you look carefully then it is behaving correctly in your version too. Notice when you click the links, the browser re-scrolls to compensate for the changing document length and tries to keep the links at the same location.

Comment: That `<br />` collection was there for a reason. @dryHumpingJava tries to show, when you click links, page scrolls to top automatically. When you remove extra `<br />` you hid the problem not solved it.